# submitHandler: function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here it my code plz help me any one

```
$(document).ready(function() {        

    // validate signup form on keyup and submit
    var validator = $("#signupform").validate({
        rules: {
            username: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6,
                maxlength: 12,                      
                remote:"users.php"

            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6,
                maxlength: 12
            },          
            email:
            {
                required: true,
                minlength: 15,
                maxlength: 50,
                remote:"email.php"
            }
        },
        messages: {
            username: {
                minlength: "username is 6 to 12 characters",
                maxlength:  "username is 6 to 12 characters",   
                required: " username should be required",
                remote: " username should be already exists"
            },
            password: {
                minlength: "password is 6 to 15 characters",
                maxlength:  "password is 6 to 12 characters 12",        
                required: " password should be required",       
            },
            email: {
                minlength: "Email is  15 to 50 characters",
                maxlength:  "Email is  15 to 50 characters",    
                required: " Email should be required",
                remote: " Email should be already exists"           
            }
        },
                 // specifying a submitHandler prevents the default submit, good for the demo       
        submitHandler: function() 
        {
            alert("submitted!---------");
            $("#signupform").submit();
        }, 
        // the errorPlacement has to take the table layout into account
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) 
                {      
            error.prependTo( element.parent().next() );
        },

        // set this class to error-labels to indicate valid fields
        success: function(label) {
            // set &nbsp; as text for IE
            label.html("&nbsp;").addClass("checked");
        }
    });


    // propose username by combining first- and lastname
    $("#username").focus(function() {
        var firstname = $("#firstname").val();
        var lastname = $("#lastname").val();
        if(firstname && lastname && !this.value) {
            this.value = firstname + "." + lastname;
        }
    }); 
});
```

And the Form is

```
<form id="signupform" name="signupform" method="post" action="register.php" style="padding-top:70px;" >             
            <table align="center" style="height:200px;">            
                   <tr>             
                    <td class="field"><span style="width:150px;color:black;font-weight:bold;">Username:</span>&nbsp;<input id="username" name="username" style="height:25px;width:155px;" onKeyPress='return alphanumericPass(event, false)' type="text" value="Username (6 to 12 chars)" maxlength="12" onfocus="if(this.value=='Username (6 to 12 chars)')this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Username (6 to 12 chars)'" placeholder="Username"  /></td>
                    <td class=""></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>                      
                    <td class="field"><span style="width:150px;color:black;font-weight:bold;">Password:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="password" name="password" style="height:25px;width:155px;" onKeyPress='return alphanumericPass(event, false)' type="password" maxlength="12" placeholder="Password" /></td>
                    <td class=""></td>
                  </tr>          
                  <tr>               
                    <td class="field" align="left"><span style="width:150px;color:black;font-weight:bold;">Email:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="email" name="email" style="height:25px;width:155px;" type="text" value="Email Address"  onfocus="if(this.value=='Email Address')this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Email Address'"/></td>
                    <td class=""></td>
                  </tr>     
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:200px;"><div><font size="1" color="#000000">By clicking 'Register Now' you are agreeing to our <a href="terms_con.php" target="_blank" style="color:red" > Terms and Conditions </a></font></div>  </td>
                    </tr>   
                <tr align="">               
                    <td class="field"  align="" colspan="2" style="padding-left:70px;">         
                    <input align="left" value="" id="signupsubmit" name="signup"  type="image" src="images/nsignup.png" />                      
                    </td>
                </tr>
             </table>

        </form>
```

Comment: Can you please provide some additional information regarding what exactly happens, when you try to submit the form via the signup-Button? Does any validation occur, do you get errors in the javascript console?

Comment: what, specifically, is wrong? is there anything in your error log? posting a lot of code and asking people to both identify the problem AND solve it is not likely to get you much help.

Comment: i am submitting the form but page not redirect to register.php.when we click on the signup button submithandler alert is not displayed.

Comment: Could you please try to condense your code to something that allows people to actually home in on the issue, or create a fiddle?

Comment: HI i am put this code in problem in godaddy server. In the local sever its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct code for submitHandler:

html:

```
<form action="/" method="post" name="myform" id="myform">
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    <!-- or
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
    -->
</form>
```

js:

```
$("#myform").validate({
   submitHandler: function(form) {
   console.log('submit');
   // other stuff

   form.submit();
   }
});
```

Comment: HI i am put this code in problem in godaddy server. In the local sever its working fine.please help me.

Comment: This is client side script (server does not affect the javascript)! Update browser cache and check all scripts/files update correctly on the server.