# How to customize submitHandler() in jQuery validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I want to validate a form using jQuery validate and then inside `submitHandler()` I want to do some stuff. But it always refreshes the page even after using `event.preventDefault()`. Here is my code

```js
$('form').validate({
            rules: {
                brand: {
                    required: true
                },
                model: {
                    required: true
                },
                description: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 15
                },
                name: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                }
            },
            messages: {
                
            },
            submitHandler: {
                function (form) {
                    form.submit( e => {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        console.log("Hello...");
                    })
                }
            }
        })
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I orginally thought you had a syntax error that breaks the plugin....

```
submitHandler: {
    function (form) {
        ....
    }
}
```

Because it normally looks like this...

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    ....
}
```

However, that idea is wrong... both formats work the same.

---

Secondly, you would never put a `event.preventDefault()` inside of the `submitHandler` callback...

- it's not even recognized here because there is no default `event` to prevent.
- the plugin is already automatically blocking the form's default submit event.

Finally, when using the `submitHandler` to run custom code, don't forget to include the default code for submitting the form as the last line in the function...

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    // your code here
    console.log("Hello...");
    form.submit(); // default form submit
}
```

Anyway, unless you fix the question by showing a demo, it's all working fine here...

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/e8xkwfzc](https://jsfiddle.net/e8xkwfzc)**

Answer (score 0):

```
submitHandler: function(form){
        alert("ok")
        return false
    }
```

add return false solves the problem

Answer (score -1):

If always refresh the page after you click the submit button, when the best way disable submit event on the form.

`<form method="post" action="/etc.php" onsubmit="return false;">
   <input type="text" value="apple">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>`

Comment: on disabling submit button form validation is not working at all

Comment: Or try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17934565/submithandler-function-not-working

Comment: this question is not related with my problem